# How to geocode where possible and skip errors with gmaps4rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, geocoding, gmaps4rails

I'm using gmaps4rails awesome gem in my current project and have to import more than a thousand objects in the DB that should act as gmappable.

However not all of them have correct addresses! So when I try to import it fails on the first address that could not be geocoded with Gmaps4rails::GeocodeStatus.

Is it possible to skip errors and geocode where possible?

I came up with this:

```
acts_as_gmappable :process_geocoding => false
before_save :prepare_gmaps    

private

def prepare_gmaps
  begin
    data = Gmaps4rails.geocode(address).first
    self.latitude= data[:lat]
    self.longitude= data[:lng]
  rescue Gmaps4rails::GeocodeStatus
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you simply try:

```
acts_as_gmappable :validation => false
```